# s3fs to mount S3 bucket with iamrole on non-aws machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3fs

I am trying to mount S3 bucket on my on-premises CentOS-6 server using s3fs as below:

```
[roots@myhost ~]# s3fs bucket-name /mnt/s3mnt -o  uid=1001,gid=1001,allow_other,umask=022,iam_role=iam-role,use_cache=/tmp
```

This gives error :

```
s3fs: unable to access MOUNTPOINT /mnt/s3mnt: Transport endpoint is not connected
debug : 
    set_moutpoint_attribute(3293): PROC(uid=0, gid=0) - MountPoint(uid=0, gid=0, mode=40777)
s3fs_init(2597): init
s3fs_check_service(2896): check services.
RequestPerform(1524): ### CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT
    RequestPerform(1617): ### retrying...
    RemakeHandle(1288): Retry request. [type=-1][url=http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/iam-role][path=]
    RequestPerform(1620): Failed to reset handle and internal data for retrying.
s3fs: Failed to check IAM role name(iam-role).
```

Please let me know if somebody did it successfully.
Tried with endpoint parameter and URL parameter but it says:

```
fuse: unknown option `endpoint=ap-northeast-1'
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got AWS credentials configured on that machine?

```
~ $ aws configure
```

And then verify with:

```
~ $ aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: yes, this point already checked. 
looks like there is some issue with the older version of fuse, without iamrole parameter it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for  me  - `/usr/bin/s3fs my-bucket /my-mount/ -o uid=500,gid=501,iam_role=MyRole,use_cache=/tmp,endpoint=ap-south-1,url=https://s3.amazonaws.com`